# how to use variables in regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have an array with some values...

```
      @array=("B_MY03", "D16", "DECAP2");
```

How to use each value to find a pattern in file that contains that value?

```
      while(<$file>){
           foreach $val(@array){
                if( $_ =~ /^item\s\=\s\w+("GR\$key\",/){...}
           }
       }
```

Pattern looks like this:

```
      Item = Type("GRB_MY03",  "DI");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my @array = ("B_MY03", "D16", "DECAP2");
my ($re) = map qr/$_/, join "|", map quotemeta, @array;


while(<$file>) {

  #       Item = Type("GRB_MY03",  "DI");
  if ( /^Item\s*=\s*\w+\("GR($re)"/ ) { ... }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub list_to_regexp {
   local $" = q(|);
   my @list = map quotemeta, @_;
   return qr/@list/;
}

my @values = ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
my $values_re = list_to_regexp(@values);

while (<DATA>)
{
   if (/^ item \s = \s ($values_re) $/x)
   {
      print "On line $. of data; found item '$1'\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
item = value3
item = value4
item = value1
primate = monkey
primate = orangutan
item = value1
primate = chimpanzee
```